# Windows 7 Command Line Add Group "Users" To File

Tags: windows-7, command-line, permissions

I need to change permissions on a file/folder through the command line. I can do this manually by:

- Right-click on any file/folder
- Properties
- Security (tab)
- Edit...
- Add...
- Enter the object names to select: **Users**
- OK

How do I do this using a command line.

Edit:

This works

```
icacls "C:\folder1\folder2\file.txt" /grant:r Users:F
```

The problem is I want to select the parent folder and for it to effect all files.

Doesn't work:

```
icacls "C:\folder" /grant:r Users:(OI)(CI)F
```

Is it because icacls can't refer to a folder??

Comment: icacls works just fine on folders.  In fact you should avoid setting permissions on files, since some stupid applications will wipe them out when a save happens.

Comment: The file only has SYSTEM and Administrators in the permission group. I think this is what is causing the problem.

Comment: Don't edit your question to add the solution. Post it as an answer separately

Comment: I can't I am too new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a batch (.bat). This is used for stubborn files that refuse to inherit the folder permissions. For command line only one %

```
FOR /R "C:\Folder" %%G IN (*.*) DO icalcs %% /grant:r Everyone:F
```

Answer (score 1):

I think icacls is what are you looking for, e.g.:

```
D:\>icacls D:\path\to\directory /grant administrators:F /t
```

Take a look: http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc753525%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: icacls is not working on these particular files. It only works if I specify the directory of the file, rather than anything in the folder.

Comment: If it isn't working, please tell us exactly what error message you are getting.

Comment: There is no error. It says Successfully processed 1 file. But when I go in to check, I get two very different results.